# Why doesn't my rgs file produce an entry in the CLSID section of the registry?

Tags: c++

I am in the process of adding a new object to my existing COM server. I have not done this recently (that is, in the last 4 years). I did not use the Wizard to add a new object but I haven’t done that in about a decade. Usually I just use copies of a previous object’s files and make the necessary changes. Now I am stuck on my new class not being registered. Of course, I has already created interfaces and implemented methods but discovered the registry problem only when my client failed to get the CoLWRPredict interface. At that point I edited the rc file to have an entry for IDR_COLWRPREDICT and creates the rgs file from an existing version. I expected to see te new registry entry after my next clean build. But no go.

I have looked at the various files that seem to be involved: resource.h, IxAsObjs.rc, and CoLWRPredict.rgs. I added the needed entries to each and everything compiles but I never get the reg entry for the CLSID. I have examined the CLSID occurrences carefully but don’t see the problem. HELP!

I include the code snippets that seem most pertinent below. But I think I failed to format the rgs file properly. Sorry.

1. from the idl file where the CLSID is set

   [
   uuid(E8D154F7-9364-4021-891F-6ABDA882B9B2),
   helpstring("CoLWRPredict Class")
   ]
   coclass CoLWRPredict
   {
    [default] interface IULWRPredict; // no IDispatch
   };

2.2. from CoLWRPredict.h where the DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID macro appears

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CCoLWRPredict
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CCoLWRPredict :
public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
public CoBasePredict,
public CComCoClass<CCoLWRPredict, &CLSID_CoLWRPredict>,
public ISupportErrorInfo,
//  public IDispatchImpl<IDALSPredict, &IID_IDALSPredict, &LIBID_IXASOBJSLib>,
public IULWRPredict
{
public:
CCoLWRPredict();
~CCoLWRPredict();

DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_COLWRPREDICT)
DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()
BEGIN_COM_MAP(CCoLWRPredict)
//  COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDLWRPredict)
//  COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(ISupportErrorInfo)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IULWRPredict)
END_COM_MAP()

STDMETHOD(InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo)(REFIID riid);

// IDLWRPredict does not exist
// IULWRPredict
public:
// snip!
```

1. resource.h where COLWRPREDICT is defined

   //{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
   // Microsoft Developer Studio generated include file.
   // Used by IxAsObjs.rc
   //

   ## define IDS_PROJNAME                        100

   ## define IDR_COHCA                               104

   ## define IDR_COTRANSFORM                         105

   // deleted entries to shorten question!…………………………..

   ## define IDR_COPLSDAPREDICT                      133

   ## define IDR_COALGLINKEDMODEL                      134

   ## define IDR_COLWRPREDICT                        135

   // Next default values for new objects
   //
   // extend _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE so that it doesn't collide with last IDR_ above

   ## ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED

   ## ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

   ## define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE            202

   ## define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE             32768

   ## define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE             201

   ## define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE               136

   ## endif

   ## endif
2. stuff from IxAsObs.rc

   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   //
   // REGISTRY
   //

   IDR_COHCA               REGISTRY DISCARDABLE            "CoHCA.rgs"
   IDR_COTRANSFORM         REGISTRY DISCARDABLE            "CoTransform.rgs"
   // deleted entries to shorten question!…………………………..
   IDR_COPLSDAPREDICT      REGISTRY DISCARDABLE            "CoPLSDAPredict.rgs"
   IDR_COALGLINKEDMODEL    REGISTRY DISCARDABLE            "CoAlgLinkedModel.rgs"
   IDR_COLWRPREDICT        REGISTRY DISCARDABLE            "CoLWRPredict.rgs"
3. CoLWRPredict.rgs

   HKCR
   {
   IxAsObjs.CoLWRPredict.1 = s 'CoLWRPredict Class'
   {
   CLSID = s '{E8D154F7-9364-4021-891F-6ABDA882B9B2}'
   }
   IxAsObjs.CoLWRPredict = s 'CoLWRPredict Class'
   {
   CLSID = s '{E8D154F7-9364-4021-891F-6ABDA882B9B2}'
   CurVer = s 'IxAsObjs.CoLWRPredict.1'
   }
   NoRemove CLSID
   {
   ForceRemove {E8D154F7-9364-4021-891F-6ABDA882B9B2} = s 'CoLWRPredict Class'
   {

   ProgID = s 'IxAsObjs.CoLWRPredict.1'
   VersionIndependentProgID = s 'IxAsObjs.CoLWRPredict'
   ForceRemove 'Programmable'
   InprocServer32 = s '%MODULE%'
   {
   val ThreadingModel = s 'Apartment'
   }
   'TypeLib' = s '{E040DFE0-A1CB-11D7-90EE-00104B317D58}'
   }
   }
   }

Comment: Well, I discovered that I had neglected to add some code to IxAsObjs.cpp. So I did that and re-built; no change in registry CLSID section. Then I rolled back my code and started over with the "Add ATL Object" wizard. It made the edits that I had made BUT when I do a clean build, STILL NO REGISTRY ENTRY in the CLSID section. WHAT IS GOING ON?

Comment: Finally I tried running regsvr32 from the command line instead of relying on the Custom Build call of regsvr32 in my VS6 project. THAT produced the desired registry entry. I guess this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old and OP has a workaround, but it looks like an issue of Visual Studio not running as admin. Can only regsvr32 with elevated privileges.